# Associative array not accessible in php

Tags: php

The situation is as follows:

There's a numerical array containing associative arrays. 
These associative arrays have 2 elements named "anfang" and "ende".

I'm now using a foreach loop to loop through the numerical array, and inside the foreach loop I want to access the associative elements, it looks like this

```
foreach($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser as $singleRequestOrReservationByUser){
   if(singleRequestOrReservationByUser["start"] > singleRequestOrReservationByUser["end"]{
   //do something
   }
}
```

Now, I'm getting the following error message into my apache2 error log

> [Mon Feb 04 11:23:16.018026 2019] [:error] [pid 1947] [client
>   127.0.0.1:41342] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   /var/www/html/include/Dauerreservierung/checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations.php:19\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/include/Dauerreservierung/checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations.php(5):
>   mainframe(Array)\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/include/Dauerreservierung/checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations.php
>   on line 19, referer: http://localhost/view/dauerreservierung.php
>   `

I don't really understand what the problem is. I've been doing this all the time on my backend in other places and it always worked. This is the first time I see this error. 
I also tried out var_dump on a single element, like this:

```
var_dump($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser[0]["anfang"];
```

And I get the same error. It seems like something is wrong with the array, but I don't understand what it is because I didn't really do anything much different from earlier.

EDIT:

The complete dump Im getting when outputting the full array is:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["anfang"]=>
    string(19) "2019-01-23 00:00:00"
    ["ende"]=>
    string(19) "2019-01-30 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have an associative array but an object. How do you declare the content of your `$allReservationsOrRequestsByUser` array? What does `var_dump($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser)` give? Does it work if you do `$singleRequestOrReservationByUser->start`?

Comment: Where's that data coming from? What makes you think that it is an array if the error message is pretty clear about it not being an array?

Comment: See the full dump in my edited post.

The data is coming from frontend which has fetched it from backend where I used json_encode on the data before sending it to frontend. There, I dont parse it or anything because I just need to pass it to another function which makes the call to backend where the above problem occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception message is self-explanatory. You're working on stdClass instead of associative arrays. Perhaps you're encoding JSON? Can you show us complete dump (`var_dump($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser)`)?

Anyway, if this is `stdClass`, to get `start` or `end` property you need to use `->`.

Comment: I edited in the full dump.
Yeah, before the JSON is sent to this backendprocess, it is fetched to frontend from another backendprocess where i use json_encode on the data.

Comment: Well, try to force it to be an associative array. Try `json_decode($jsonString, true)`. That second boolean parameter set to `true` should give you what you need.